# CSS Divs not displaying height property

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS that is displaying 3 horizontal divs, centre window:

```
.chatarea {
    display: table;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:80%;
}
.nick {
    width: 20%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}
.timestamp {
    width: 20%;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
}
.message {
    border-style: solid;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

when the content/text gets longer the height of the borders does not expand.

i have created a fiddle here too: http://jsfiddle.net/fGSsa/

Comment: Can we get a description in words of the result you are looking for including how you want the different areas to react as content inside them changes. Your positioning definitely seems off. I think you might just be making it ahrder than it needs to be.

Comment: i just want the divs to expand their height as they need to - should i just use a table?

Comment: yes, just use a table.

Answer (score 4):

You are presenting data in a tabular format. Use a `<table>`.

When that CSS tutorial you read said tables are some terrible evil thing, they meant that using tables for presentation/layout is terrible/evil.

When presenting tabular data, it is semantically accurate to use a `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use html tables

OR if you still want to use divs :

You should add a class row

```
   .row  {
        display: table-row;
        }
```

then

```
.nick, .timestamp, .message {
    display: table-cell;
    }
```

Please check the link 
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Comment: I'd upvote this if you reordered the statements: first use a table, it's the right thing to do IMO, only then the right solution for the square wheel approach.

Comment: I mean, first tell him to use a <table> element (the right thing in this case IMO), and only then provide him with the solution for the not-so-great approach he had chosen. Then again, this is just my oppinion.

Comment: I agree with you :) @LexLythius